# javac: File Not Found Error in Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to build a docker image for a java app.
I have done the following in the dockerfile :

```
FROM java:8
RUN javac HelloDocker.java
CMD ["java","HelloDocker"]
```

When I am trying to build the image it is throwing the following exception :`javac: file not found: HelloDocker.java`
The HelloDocker.java file and Dockerfile is in the same directory.
Also, when I tried to compile the java file separately (via javac HelloDocker.java), it did not throw any error.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a deprecated image. You should be using `openjdk` image. See the below

https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/

Also you need `javac` so you should be using the one with `jdk` tag and not the `jre` tag.

So try `openjdk:8-jdk`

**Edit-1**

Also you need to copy the files inside your Dockerfile. When you use `docker build .`, then the current directory files as available to you as context but they are not inside image

```
FROM java:8
WORKDIR /app
COPY HelloDocker.java .
RUN javac HelloDocker.java
CMD ["java","HelloDocker"]
```

Comment: the problem is not with javac not being found

Comment: @Tarun thanks for the answer. The issue was not setting the WORKDIR.After setting the WORKDIR in the dockerfile it is working!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is the complete Dockerfile, you need to have a file named HelloDocker.java in your docker image's file system, before you can compile the file using "RUN javac HelloDocker.java" . You may copy the file from your host's file system to you docker image using docker COPY/ADD command.